# CSS set scrollbar outside content

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a table with two columns. When the first column is bigger than window height, it must have scroll. So I use a div inside cell with height 100% and scroll auto.

My problem is that when "the cell" has scroll, his content is hidden by ...the scrollbar.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="table">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div>
            <a href="/">Link 1</a>
            <a href="/">Link 2</a>
            <a href="/">Link 3</a>
            <a href="/">Link 4</a>
            <a href="/">Link 5</a>
            <a href="/">Link 6</a>
            <a href="/">Link 7</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Content page</div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
body,html{width:100%; height:100%}
#table{display:table; width:100%; height:100%; background:#eee;}
#table div.sidebar{display:table-cell; vertical-align:top; height:0px; overflow:hidden; background:#4d5b69;}
#table div.sidebar div{height:100%; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;}
#table div.sidebar a{display:block; padding:7px 0px 7px 0px; font-weight:bold; white-space:nowrap; border-bottom:1px solid #5b7289; color:#fff;}
#table div.sidebar a span{color:#fff;}
#table div.sidebar a i{min-width:20px; color:#fff; display:inline-block;}
#table div.sidebar a:hover{background:#364a5e}
#table div.sidebar a.logo{padding:10px; text-align:center; font-size:40px;}
#table div.content{display:table-cell; width:100%; height:100%; vertical-align:top; padding:10px;}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NQAzt/265/

Please simulate page as height 200px just to see that the first column (because of scrollbar) hides his content.

I need to fix this without setting width in pixels for cell.

I also don't want to use javascript.

There is anyway to show all content, without hiding it when "the cell" has scrollbar ?

**Edit**: Seems that in chrome is working fine, but not in firefox (50)...

Print from firefox:

[print firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTf0F.jpg)

Comment: Seems to work fine in Chrome. I don't see any scrollbar appearing in IE11. 
What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: Oh... seems like in Chrome is working as I need....